# How can I create a custom plugin that allows anonymous users to signup without registering?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, user-access

I am very new to wordpress. I want to create a small Booking System as a plugin. I have 5 different pages for entering details step by step and Users can book as anonymous. Admin only need a mail with all those details.

How can I allow access for anonymous users in these pages?

What is the appropriate method and hooks to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be using options pages for the public - create a regular page (post) and use it as placeholder for your booking form (either autocreate on plugin activiation and/or have a setting in the admin for choosing which page will act as your placeholder). See how plugins like PaidMemberships Pro & WooCommerce do it.

Answer (score 2):

I would look into a Booking Plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/booking/, for example) or if you need to collect information from users look no further than Gravity Forms(http://gravityforms.com) or Ninja Forms(http://ninjaforms.com).

@TheDeadMedic is correct, you should not use add_options_page() for front-end pages.